# Showing there is a model of PA whose ordering is $\aleph_1$-like

Tags: logic, model-theory

This is problem 4.5.15 of Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*; this is purely for review purposes, and is not homework.

Marker defines an ordering $(X,<)$ to be *$\aleph_1$-like* if $|X|$ is $\aleph_1$, but the cardinality of every initial segment of the ordering is $\leq\aleph_0$. The problem is then to show there is a model of PA whose ordering is $\aleph_1$-like.

**What does a solution to this look like?**

I have no hunch for how to solve this, nor even much of an idea what the right tools might be. Chapter 4 is on types and saturation, and the mention of cardinals suggests I ought to be looking at this through the lens of saturation, homogeneity, or stability; but there are no further hints and I wasn't able to see a similarity with any examples earlier in the chapter.

Comment: Are you familiar with the MacDowell-Specker theorem?

Comment: Certainly stability won't be relevant - $\mathsf{PA}$ is about as unstable as it gets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a particularly simple proof by general model-theoretic results. Rather, this is a situation where a particular theorem about $\mathsf{PA}$ is the key:

> **(MacDowell-Specker Theorem)** Every model of $\mathsf{PA}$ has an elementary end extension (of the same cardinality, via downward Lowenheim-Skolem).

(See [here](https://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198568278.001.0001/acprof-9780198568278-chapter-2). Interestingly, my memory is that this result only applied to *countable* models of $\mathsf{PA}$, but that appears incorrect; I think I'm misremembering a more complicated result about elementary extensions of models of $\mathsf{PA}$, and will mention it for contrast once I find it. Certainly though the MacDowell-Specker Theorem for countable models would be enough here.)

By iterating $\omega_1$-many times *(taking unions at limit stages - this is fine since the extensions are elementary, so we're just taking the union of an elementary chain when we do this)*, we can build an $\aleph_1$-like model of $\mathsf{PA}$ as desired: that the cardinality is $\aleph_1$ is trivial, and that all proper initial segments are countable follows from the fact that we built our model via end extensions only.

Comment: The MacDowell-Specker Theorem is Theorem 4.2.5 in Marker (though it is not given this name).

Comment: Ah, I see the connection now. That every countable model of PA has an elementary end extension is something you can get at purely by omitting countably many types, and then it's just the elementary chain theorem, yeah?